# How to make a stopwatch with PHP?

Tags: php

I want the timer to be activated at a specific time on the server, if the page is reloaded, follow the timer where it left off, not to restart, in the same way if you close the browser, let the timer continue? I have no idea how to do it, or is it possible? any ideas? I thank you too much.

Comment: You can write it to database. User must login for this.

Comment: user_id,counter and another db fields

Comment: I think you dont want a "stopwatch". You want to know the start time something happened (f.e. a unix timestamp). This timestamp you can put into a session, db, cache, ... and check how many time elapsed since then.
_But we actually do not know what you plan to do ... ._

Answer (score 0):

You could save the information in the session (if the user then clears their cookies, the stopwatch is lost):

```
session_start();

if (array_key_exists('stopwatch', $_SESSION)) {
    $stopwatch = $_SESSION['stopwatch'];
} else {
    $stopwatch = time();
    $_SESSION['stopwatch'] = $stopwatch;
}

$elapsed = time() - $stopwatch;

print "Elapsed time: " . date('H:i:s', $elapsed);
```

If not in a session, then in a database (you will need a login then, because each user will need their own stopwatch).

If you wanted to time the page as it stays open, you'd need AJAX and a Javascript timer that updated the server-side session or database-based stopwatch. You would then have two times, the total time (stopwatch started three hours ago) and screen time (the browser displayed the stopwatch for 1h 17' of those 3 hours).

To clear the session stopwatch just delete the variable:

```
unset($_SESSION['stopwatch']);
```

As regards the "timer will continue" after the user has left, this sorts of work as long as you don't require anything to happen on the server (such as doing something when the stopwatch hits eight hours, for example). To do *that* you need a much higher dregree of control over the server, and would probably need what is called a "cron job" to run there or on an external server that you control.

As things are, above, you can *resume* the stopwatch knowing how much time has elapsed - *just as if* the stopwatch had continued running for the whole time.